# Is there a good list of things left out of the Compact Framework?

Tags: compact-framework, reference

I'm looking for a list of things left out of the Compact Framework, so I don't have to stumble over each one. For instance, I've just discovered the Message struct is not directly available. No big deal, but I spent an hour thinking I had done something wrong, since all the compiler says is "Are you missing a using statement?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they state, it is not a complete reference, but there is a good list on msdn.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2weec7k5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2weec7k5.aspx) explaining the differences between .NET Compact and regular .NET frameworks.